# Epson XP-600 will not print properly with all new ink recently installed

Tags: printer, printing

I just installed brand new Epson 273 ink cartridges *($64 worth!)* in my Epson XP-600 printer. One box had all the colors plus black, and one had the fatter black cartridge.

I am not getting ANY black print on paper, although, when I lift the cartridges out, they show ink inside. Now the yellow is saying `LOW` though all cartridges are less than 2 weeks old. I only use this printer sparingly—not for business or work reasons. I am ready to scream, as the ink cost almost as much as the actual printer (which is barely 7 months old)!

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the printheads? pg. 20 in your printer's [quick-start guide](http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/xp600_/xp600_qr.pdf).

Comment: seems like your printer is a bit bunked.

Comment: You're probably printing in color without intending to, which won't use the black cartridge.  Try setting the print job explicitly to B/W only and that will usually do it.  Since the color cartridges are expensive, and inkjet cartridges don't print many pages, I'd suggest you set B/W as the default in the printer driver preferences. (You don't say what OS you're using, so I'm not including instructions.)  Also you don't say if you tried cleaning the cartridges w/the printer's function for it, or wiping the heads with alcohol, in case it's clogged.

Comment: Epson cartridges in an Epson printer? Ask them to (help you) make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar experience - twice. The first time I got flooded with yellow, got it fixed under warranty and now it has just happened again after adding new black ink cartridges. This time flooding with cyan. Back to the repair shop. I have just spent $400 in new extra large cartridges. Back to the repair shop on Monday. I only use my Canon XP600 for printing CDs.

Solution - buy a Brother printer which has a CD printer tray.

The printer had a fault caused by downloading an update when I installed the drivers for a new computer. Don't install any updates offered if you are asked!

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the black and photo black cartridges and the printer would not print at all. I tried reinstalling and trouble-shooting and got nowhere. Gave up for 24 hours. Then I took out the new cartridges, shook them over the sink and heard (and saw) black ink. I put them back in and now it prints perfectly. Hope you get lucky, too. The XP-600 is certainly not a product Epson can be proud of - will not buy the brand again.